# Qt: Updates can only be scheduled from GUI thread or from QQuickItem::updatePaintNode

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qquickitem

How can call `update()` on `QQuickItem` from a worker thread without causing the following warning?

```
Updates can only be scheduled from GUI thread or from QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()
```

I want to enforce `QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()` to execute.

I tried the solution of hooking a `QObject::connect` from the worker thread to a slot which calls `MyQQuickItem->update()`. **Everything works fine though**. `QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()` is called after the signal emit & the `QQuickItem` is updated *the way I want*. But I get this warning on every update call I schedule which *I understand as you cannot update UI from worker thread*. But what is the way to do this without a warning in Qt?

**BUT, How can I get rid the warning that I get on every update call?**

**Note:** I had to make the `QObject::connect` with a `Qt::DirectConnection` since a `Qt::QueuedConnection` did not work for calling update through a signal.

**Checked** through [this discussion here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/64596-Using-QQuickView-in-separate-thread-problems). Discussion in this link ends with a complain about the same warning that I am getting here. My question is what should I correct to avoid that warning?

Comment: read this: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/64596-Using-QQuickView-in-separate-thread-problems

Comment: @eyllanesc I've read that [link](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/64596-Using-QQuickView-in-separate-thread-problems) you provided. As I mentioned in my question as well - I understand that one cannot call `update` from a worker thread. **But I thought Qt signal slot will take care of that as mentioned in that link ?** I not calling update directly as well. It is through a signal slot

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you use `Qt::DirectConnection`, the slot is called in the worker thread, you should use `Qt::QueuedConnection` (or `Qt::AutoConnection`). Why isn't it working?

Comment: @m7913d I have a `GLuint` in the signal & slot. if I use `Qt::AutoConnection`, it complains "cannot queue arguments of type GLuint. Make sure 'GLuint' is registered using qRegisterMetaType()`. `Qt::QueuedConnection` does not work at all. it doesnt even throw any error

Comment: You should indeed register it to be able to use it in a queued connection.

Comment: yes. queued connection works nicely across threads. thanks @m7913d

Comment: also, I should not pass by reference in a signal slot across threads? (*UI thread & worker thread in this case*) Is my understanding correct?.  I want to pass const references but reading through the signal slot internals, I see that it is un-advisable to pass by reference? Please confirm

Comment: According to [this link](http://www.embeddeduse.com/2013/06/29/copied-or-not-copied-arguments-signals-slots/), you should pass it always by reference. Qt will take care of creating some copies when necessary (to implement the asynchronous behavior/queued connection)

Comment: Note that Qt itself declares its arguments as const references (for complex datatypes)

Comment: ok. looks like I should pass by const ref & let Qt create extra copies if required. thanks for sharing the info @m7913d

Comment: In the case of worker thread being non-qt, say std::thread; we could call a lambda functor from such worker. Just capture the this pointer of QObject(having affinity to the main thread) in the lambda's capture list and then while the lambda body is executing (in worker's context i.e.) use QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, []() { xxxxx }, Qt::QueuedConnection) . "xxxx" code would then be queued to the main thread's event loop.